# getting start and end dates of ther week that precedes the given date

Tags: php, date

I am selecing a date from jquery datepicker and I want to pick the starting and ending date of the week that precedes this date. - for example picking April 10, 2013 should return March 31, 2013 and April 6, 2013.
Sunday is the first day of the week and Saturday is last.

Below is my code.

```
$weekday = $d->format('w');
$diff = 7 + ($weekday == 0 ? 6 : $weekday - 0); //to make week start from monday till     sunday add 1 to weekday -

$start1 = $d->modify("-$diff day");
$start_date = $d->format('Y-m-d');  

$end1 =  $d->modify('+6 day');
$stop_date = $d->format('Y-m-d');
```

The code works fine, at least mostly. However, when I pick any sunday I get a wrong a non expected result which is the previous week of the previous week.
for example, if I select March 31, 2013 - I should get march 24 and march 30,, but I am getting march 28 and march 24.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: There are n+1 number of similar questions.

Comment: @hjpotter92. can you kindly show a link to any one ? (or find the value of n, apparently you have lots of time)

Comment: ok im here to help you so help me help you ok?

Comment: Look at the related column in the right.

Comment: @hjpotter92. you only get those after you ask the question.

Comment: You also get them while asking the question.

Comment: @imsiso what data u need ?

Comment: @hjpotter92. the answer you provided gives the current week. kindly, before acting smarty and the next big zucherberg, read the question well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should solve your problem:

```
$input = 'April 10, 2013'; // come from jquery

$dt = new DateTime($input . ' -1week');

$monday = clone $dt->modify(('Sunday' == $dt->format('l')) ? 'Monday last week' : 'Monday this week');
$sunday = clone $dt->modify('Sunday this week');

printf("You've selected a date in the week from %s to %s\n",
    $monday->format('Y-m-d'),
    $sunday->format('Y-m-d')
);
```